# How to improve battery life of Dell Vostro 3558 running Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dell, power-management, battery

The specifications are i3 4th gen, 8gb ram, 240gb SSD, 1Tb HDD, Nvidia 820m.

I have installed Nvidia X server configuration and Nvidia server and switched to intel low power graphics but not much difference, in Windows 10 I get easily up to 3-3.5 hrs but in Ubuntu, I hardly get 1-1.5 hrs.

I have also installed tlp but it doesn't make much difference.

Any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are chances that your CPU frequency is always at full speed, which of course, doesn't save energy.

From Terminal Try to :

```
sudo apt-get install cpufreqd cpufrequtils indicator-cpufreq
```

Then launch indicator-cpufreq with :

```
indicator-cpufreq &
```

Then choose **Powersave** policy from the applet on top which just appeared